# Authenticated Referrals vs. OAuth - post informations to website?

Tags: facebook, referrals

At the moment i use the PHP serverside OAuth-Authentification by creating a "Login by facebook" button.
As the App also is in the sidebar, i want to use the authentificated referrals for users to directly access that App.
The problem is that, even though the access may be granted, i need to get this login-query-string to my website to save all access tokens, informations etc.

So - how exactly can i set the url to redirect the user to after the app is given permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user is sent to your app facebook will also send the auth data along with the request.
In the [Authenticated Referrals](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals) section of the [Auth Dialog documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication) it says:

> 3 . Auth Token Parameter: If Authenticated Referrals is enabled and
>   when a user authorizes your app through the in-line Auth Dialog, we
>   will pass your app the Auth Token in the format specified here.
>   Available formats:
>
> - URI Fragment: if your app is using client-side authentication
> - Query String: if your app is using server-side authentication. If your app is a canvas app, we will not use this setting and will use
>     the "signed_request" as the response type automatically.

If your app is a canvas app you'll simply get all the needed data with the "signed_request", otherwise it will be part of the querystring.
For more user data you then simply make api requests.